# Opening new workspace from child viewmodel

Tags: wpf, mvvm

i've written a project that is based on the MVVM customer example on MSDN. How would i add a new workspace from a child view model? I don't like the idea of making the Workspaces collection static as this seems to go against the pattern.

i'm effectively trying to add a new customer view when an element in the allcustomers view is double clicked.

thanks in advance

Comment: a view model - the parent view model contains an observable collection of these view models(they are referred to as workspaces in the msdn example). These view models are then displayed in a tab control

Answer (score 0):

One "simple" solution is to pass the ParentViewModel into the child ViewModel's constructor. Then you can simple call the Add logic on the ParentViewModel from wherever you want in the child's code.

Comment: i tried this and it definitely works, but i didn't like this. In the end i decided to add an event to the child view model. the parent view model listens for this and and then responds with its own logic. i don't think that child view models should know anything about their parent. thanks for the advice though

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an older post, but, for the record, I added a static WorkspaceManager class that exposes methods for adding and activating Workspaces.  The WorkspaceManager maintains the Workspaces collection.  Any class can call the static methods, so the Main window or parent doesn't have to maintain the Workspaces collection or have any knowledge on how the Workspace functionality is actually implemented.

J